How to understand "Only undefined length bursts can have a BUSY transfer as the last cycle of a burst"?
This sentence comes from AMBA AHB Protocol Specification(IHI 0033C) page 3-30. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0033/c/?lang=en
For my understand, if the AHB manager launch a write operation with burst type INCR4, that means it can't insert  transfer type BUSY immediately after the INCR4 write  operation finished.
To be specific, the last beat of one INCR4 write operation includes available address about this cycle and available HWDATA about the last cycle, so the available HWDATA of this cycle needs to be launched in the next cycle by AHB manager. Therefore, the next cycle's transfer type can be IDLE or NONSEQ with available HWDATA but can not be BUSY.
I need to imitate the AHB manager's behavior to build a testbench, so I want to know if I understand the spec correctly. Since English is not my born language, please let me know my expression mistake if it exists. And thank you for your patience reading my problem.
